# Java Class with Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Java class that is used for a companies different branches located around the Country, and each branch will keep a track of its client list. How can i implement this so that "London" branch only pulls the list of clients that has used that branch, but not able to see the client list of other branches? I am thinking of a client class that contains an array, but im struggling to find a way of linking the classes together

```
public class Branch implements Manager {

//instance variables that will be available to children of Branch
private String branchName;



// constructor
public Branch(String name) {
    this.branchName = name;
}


//Returns the location of the branch as a String
@Override
public String getBranch() {
    return this.branchName;
}

//Returns a String representation of customers who have used the Branch
@Override
public String getAllCustomers() {
    return "Customer list will go here";
}
```

Comment: You do realize that if you put the array as a private member of the class, it will only be directly accessible to the particular object only?

Comment: sure, but instances will be created of the branch class, which means "London" will be able to see the client list of "Glasgow"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Map<String, List<Clients>>
```

?

So you can map a branch to a list of clients.

Answer (score 0):

If `class London extends Branch` and `class Glasgow extends Branch` then `London` will not be able to get private fields of `Glagow`. `London` and `Glasgow` will not be able even to access private members delared in `Branch`

Use `protected` or package protected access modifiers.